# Android - SQLite db keeps showing rows that should have been deleted

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently creating an app that downloads lists from a server and places those lists into an SQLite database. In the Mainactivity it calls the lists from the db and places them into a custom adapter, everything works fine and such.

After this I go through several screens to proces the listdata and in the final activity it uses a query to delete the row it's been working on from the db. I use logcat to print the db after this and it shows that the row has been deleted.

Next it takes me back to the Mainactivity and in its onResume I once again load the lists from the db only to find that the row that should have been deleted is still in it. The listview is being updated correctly, it's really an issue of retrieving data from the database that should have been deleted.

So, anybody has an idea why I get rows that have been deleted in another activity?

Mainactivity:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    context = getApplicationContext();

    ConsLoadListDataSource cllDataSource = new ConsLoadListDataSource(context);
    cllDataSource.open();
    list = cllDataSource.sqliteToListIds();
    cllDataSource.close();

    logcat("Jadajada: " + list.toString());

}
```

SQLiteHelper:

```
public List<String> sqliteToListIds() {
    List<String> conList= new ArrayList<>();

    if (!db.isOpen()) {
        open();
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ConsLoadListSQLHelper.TABLE_CONS_HEADER,
            allConsListColumns, null, null, "loadlist" , null, "loadlist");
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        conList.add(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();

    return conList;
}
```

The deleting method works, but since it's being asked for:

```
public void deleteList(int id) {
    if (!db.isOpen()) {
        open();
    }

    db.delete(ConsLoadListSQLHelper.TABLE_CONS_HEADER,
            ConsLoadListSQLHelper.CONS_HEADER_ID + " = " + id,  null);

    db.close();
}
```

**edit**

I've found a workaround solution by deleting the row on my server and once again retrieving all data from the server before I go back to my MainActivity, but I still don't know how to solve the original problem and this makes my app more dependent on an internet connection, so it's not perfect, but will have to do for now.

Comment: Deleting isn't the issue, so I didn't add the code. After I deleted the row I called the full db in the same activity and it shows the row as deleted. The problem is that after this check I go back to my Mainactivity and it still shows the row there. But I'll add the delete method for good measure.

Comment: The Listview also isn't the problem, I've tested this and it works as it should. The issue is that it still retrieves data from the db that should have been deleted.

Comment: Apparently not since I have this issue.

Comment: The issue is that it retrieves the wrong/deleted info from the db. I use logcat to check the data from my db before it gets loaded into the adapter and the row is still in it. So it doesn't matter what I do, the issue lies there and not with the listview or adapter.

Comment: I still don't have a solution, it still retrieves the deleted row and I don't have any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting single item you have to use

```
public void deleteRule(String value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Table_Name, Key_value + " = ?",
                new String[] { value });
        db.close();

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my delete method works. It's afterwards that the troubles start.

Comment: You are loading files from server so file is deleted from your local database not from server database.

Comment: The data gets retreived from the server and put into my SQLite db before loading the Mainactivity and from that moment on I only use the SQLite db.

Comment: so actually whats your question?

Comment: Why do I get rows that have been deleted in another activity?

Comment: //change this line and try   -  private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: List<String> details = cllDataSource.sqliteToListIds(); //try this

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've found a workaround solution, but thanks anyway.